# Copying Cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I don't know if stackoverflow is the right place for this question:

I have an Excel table with values in the cells C3, G3, K3 and so on...
Now i want to copy these values in the cells B27, B28, B29 and so on...

Can I manage this in the Excel command line or do I need to write some VBA code?
(I'm using Office 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in cell B27 and copy down as far as you need:
  `=OFFSET(C$3, 0, (ROW()-27) * 4)`

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but in excel you can simply reference a cell to get it's value, so in C3 enter =B27, and the value from C3 will appear. Repeat for the other cell values you'd like to copy

Comment: Yes, but I have very much values and I don't want to type this in every single cell manually (by the way I want to copy the value of C3 in B27 - B27=C3)
if I write in B27=C3 and in B28=G3 and I drag these cells down -> B29=C5 and B30=G5

Comment: Ah, yes. Excel doesn't seem to infer patterns very well in that direction. You may need to write some VBA code to get that effect